# Iterate through template in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement wherein I need to iterate over a template currently I am using the code as:

```
    <xsl:template match="CorporateEntity">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="AccountEntity" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AccountEntity">
      <xsl:variable name="Reference" select="/CDFTransmissionFile/TransmissionHeader_1000/FileReferenceNum"/>
      <TrvCreditCardTransactionEntity>
        <Reference>
          <xsl:value-of select="$Reference"/>
        </Reference>
        <CardNumber>
          <xsl:value-of select="@AccountNumber"/>        
        </CardNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FinancialTransactionEntity" />
      </TrvCreditCardTransactionEntity>xsl:template match
    </xsl:template>
```

However this is going through only one AccountEntity it seems & in my xml file I am having multiple AccountEntity. Could anyone please help me here?

Comment: Please show minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT, output or result you want and the one you get, to allow us to reproduce and understand the problem. It also helps if you tell us exactly which XSLT processor and XSLT version you use or target as the answer might depend on that.